# Exchange 2013 & Active directory user details

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I have a problem that is driving me nuts.

We recently rolled out Exchange 2013 (coexisting with exchange 2007), and have a 2008R2 active directory.

The problem we are facing is that when we change user details in active direcotry, job title or telephone number for example, these are not reflected in exchange, and therefore are not reflected in the offline address book on outlook.

The only way we get it to work is to make the changes on recipient mailbox itself.

I'm confused if this is by design or something wrong. Please advise, thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused if this is by design or something wrong

Something is wrong, assuming you are using the right attribute for telephonenumber, but kind of hard to get job title wrong.

Are you waiting long enough for AD to replicate to Exchange and for the OAB to actually generate properly on the server?  Make a title change and wait 24 hours.  Does it work then?  If not, then check your event logs on your Exchange server (assuming only one, if not, check each mailbox server) for replication issues.

Also, when you change them in the recipient mailbox do the changes then reflect in AD?  If so, then the replication should be working fine and should be bi-directional.  Again, you may simply not be waiting long enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would also check firewall settings. Make sure DCs and exchange servers are able to communicate with each other. Is the behavior same on Exchange 2007 and Exchange 2013?